# Add rewrite location with Puppet / Nginx

Tags: nginx, puppet

I'd like to use this rule in Nginx config file :

```
    # Redirect old application
    if ($host ~ (\w+).domain.com) {
        set $root $1;
    }

    # Redirect old application
    if ($host = app1.domain.com) {
        rewrite ^ $scheme://app2.domain.com permanent;
    }
```

But I can't figure out how to transfer this to a puppet using the standard [Nginx module](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppet/nginx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Puppet `nginx` module has attributes for appending arbitrary raw text to location and server sections. For example, see the [`nginx::resource::location` manifest](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-nginx/blob/master/manifests/resource/location.pp#L67) for its full list of attributes, which includes `raw_append`.

In theory, your configuration could be as simple as something like

```
include nginx

nginx::resource::location { 'example.com/path/'
  ensure     => present,
  location   => '/path/',
  server     => 'example.com',
  raw_append => @(END),
    # Redirect old application
    if ($host ~ (\w+).domain.com) {
        set $root $1;
    }

    # Redirect old application
    if ($host = app1.domain.com) {
        rewrite ^ $scheme://app2.domain.com permanent;
    }
    END
}
```